# Installing Redmine on bluehost

Tags: ruby, redmine, rubygems

I'm installing redmine on a bluehost server, and thanks to scripts like [this one](http://www.bernawebdesign.ch/byteblog/2009/07/02/installing-redmine-on-bluehost-shared-hosting/), most of everything is covered (except the `RAILS_ENV=production rake config/initializers/session_store.rb` step). However, when I try to run redmine, it claims that it can't fine hoe, even though it is installed. I was able to figure out what was wrong thanks to [this site](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=27697) and a comment in the gem manager of my cpanel: it isn't picking up locally installed gems. Cpanel claims the solution is to add `$:.push("/home4/gametisi/ruby/gems")` to my script, but I don't know where to add it. Can anyone help?

The specific error message I'm getting is:

```
(in /home4/gametisi/rails_apps/redmine)
rake aborted!
Could not find RubyGem hoe (>= 1.3.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working by adding `ENV['GEM_PATH'] ||= '(my path to ruby gems as found with the command gem environment)'` before executing `rake` commands.

I was able to start redmine without error and access the application locally using lynks (my setup put it on port 12009, not port 80), and in order to open up the port to the outside world, I needed to add dedicated IP to my server setup. I'm waiting for the DNS to propagate, at which point I am told I will be able to access the app.

Comment: While Redmine was able to run at this point, I couldn't access it remotely. I finally discovered that bluehost had opened up port 12009 for outbound traffic, not inbound traffic - after switching that around, all was good.